# Handsontable redraw

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to update the data source json via

```
hot = new Handsontable(container,
.....
```

in somewhere in the code:

```
hot.getData().push({/*...*/ });
```

I want to redraw the hot in html-page after this line. How to force do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing what you're asking. Here I present two of them, pulled almost straight out of the documentation page.

The first is using the `loadData` function:

> ```
> loadData (data: Array)
>     Reset all cells in the grid to contain data from the data array
> ```

This one is self explanatory. The thing with it is that it will trigger `hot.render()` automatically, as well as a few other events (like `afterChange`).

If you didn't want to do that, you can use the second method which is more "raw". This one involves basic javascripts principles. Handsontable is initialized with a reference to your `data` object. If you were to mutate this object, and then render, it would be the same as using `loadData` but without triggering the events.

Comment: Doesn't loadData consume processor time much more that  hot.getData().push(...) ?

Comment: And what is the difference between my code and your 'raw' method? I think I do the same. Or am I not right?

Comment: Not sure how you came to the conclusion that `loadData` consumes much more processor time since all it does is replace the data reference and re-render, plus triggers events. What I meant to say is that with your raw method, doing `hot.getData().push(...)` would only allow you to push data, not update it, and it feels like not the best programming approach. You should be keeping the reference to your data object in any case so modifying this directly would make more sense. For example, `hot.getData()` might be returning a clone, and not the reference, so you'd fall into a pitfall.